# SSIS importing extra decimal values in to destination sql table from excel

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to import "Financial data" from Excel files in to sql table. Problem I am facing is that My ssis package is incrementing decimal values. e.g   -(175.20) from Excel is being loaded as "-175.20000000000005" in SQL.
I am using nVArChar (20) in destination SQL table. Images attached. What's the best data type in destination table. I have done a lot of reading and people seem to suggest decimal data but Package throws error for Decimal data type.Need help please.[image: Sql Extract]
[image: Source Excel File]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up changing the Data type to "Currency" in my SQL destination. Then added a data conversion task to change "DT_R8" data type from excel source to "currency[DT_CY]. This resolved the issue. could have used decimal or Numeric (16,2)data type in my destination as well but then i just went ahead with currency and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Derived Column Transformation in your Data Flow Task, with an expression like `ROUND([GM],2)` (you might need to replace `GM` with whatever your actual column name is).

You can then go to the Advanced Editor of the Derived Column Transformation and set the data type to decimal with a Scale of 2 on the 'Input and Output Properties' tab (look under 'Derived Column Output').

You'll then be able to use a decimal data type in your SQL Server table.

Comment: Many thanks Chris. I will give it a try tomorrow. Will let you know the end result.